# Why is Javascript causing my page to crash?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

so I'm using MVC 4 C#/Razor and I'm developing a page that uses SlickGrid to display grid data.  Everything works fine, except when I try using it to display a large amount of data (something like 1 million rows).

When this happens, it appears to do just fine until it's just about finished.  Right when it seems like it's going to be done with all dataloading, the web page crashes.  I use getJSON to pull the data from a SQL database.  I do it by column, and in batches of 300000 records.  I have tried using Chrome memory profiling tools, and wasn't able to find anything useful.  Below is some code snippets:

```
    function pullAllGridData(tableName, colArray)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < colArray.length; i++)
        {
            fetchColumn(tableName, colArray[i], 0);
        }
    }


    function fetchColumn(tableName, fieldName, startAt)
    {
        $.getJSON('/WIMenu/GetTableData', { tableName: tableName, fieldName: fieldName }, function (data)
        {
            if (data.slice(-1) !== '~')
            {
                var startPass = populateSlickData(data, fieldName, startAt);
                colStatus[fieldName] = true;
                if (loadFirstBatch())
                { populateGrid(); }
                fetchColumn(tableName, fieldName, startPass);
            }
            else
            {
                data = data.slice(0, -1);
                populateSlickData(data, fieldName, startAt);
                colStatus[fieldName] = true;
                if (loadFirstBatch())
                { populateGrid(); }
            }
        });
    }

    function populateSlickData(input, fieldName, startAt)
    {
            var output = startAt;
            var valueArray = input.split('|');
            output += valueArray.length;
            if (!isInBlackList(fieldName, tableName))
            {
                var datatype = columns[getColumnIndex(fieldName)].datatype;
                var startIndex = startAt;
                var endIndex = startAt + valueArray.length;
                var counter = 0;
                alert(fieldName + ': startIndex: ' + startIndex + ' endIndex: ' + endIndex + ' count: ' + endIndex-startIndex);
                for (var x = startIndex; x < endIndex; x++)
                {
                    if (!slickdata[x])
                    { slickdata[x] = {}; }
                    if (valueArray[x - startAt] == 'null') { valueArray[x - startAt] = ''; }
                    if (datatype == 'System.DateTime')
                    {
                        if (valueArray[x-startAt] !== '')
                        {
                            var date = new Date(valueArray[x - startAt]);
                            valueArray[x - startAt] = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (datatype == 'System.Decimal' || datatype == 'System.Int32' || datatype == 'System.Int16' || datatype == 'System.Int64')
                    {
                        valueArray[x - startAt] = parseFloat(valueArray[x - startAt]);
                    }
                    slickdata[x][fieldName] = valueArray[x - startAt];
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            currentColumn = fieldName;

        filteredData = slickdata;
        return output;
    }
```

fetchColumn uses recursion to keep getting column data until all of it has been received.  The populateGrid method simply syncs the SlickGrid object to the slickdata object.  My goal here is to find out why the page is crashing and learn how it can be fixed.

Through using alerts, it seems that at some point, it gets stuck in the for loop in the populateSlickData method, and I cant figure out why.  I've tried printing the for indexing data, but it all seems to be normal.

Comment: Really interesting, is the recursion really necessary? Would not be more efficient to perform just one ajax call and return everything?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico - I don't see any recursion in the sample... There is indeed callback calling the out function again, but I'd not call it recursion.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov there is in the fetchColumn function.

Comment: Side note: In other professions it may be called [wing load test](http://jalopnik.com/5504530/boeing-787-dreamliner-ultimate-wing-load-test)... Indeed any piece of software/hardware will break if you put enough load on it. Some are more resistant, but really 1 million records for showing in browser?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico - I see what you mean - it is just your definition of recursive function is different from mine than. I'd not consider asynchronous callback to be recursive call, but it may be old synchronous thinking...

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I originally did that, but it was pulling so much data that it caused a memory overflow.  So, I decided to segment it so that it would work.

Comment: "the web page crashes" you mean: the browser tab? The browser itself? The controller serving the data (and the web application with that?)

Comment: I think people are missing the forest for the trees. He's loading a MILLION rows of data INTO MEMORY at the same time.

Comment: A million rows, from JSON, in a browser. A server could handle that load, sure, but even if the browser can hold that much data/many objects, rendering it will not go well.

Comment: @LorenzoDematté the browser tab crashes.  The controller/web browser as a whole do not crash or fail.

Comment: For me it is a simple problem that a server paging shall resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pull a million rows of data **into memory** and expect any web page to do anything other than slow to a crawl, or indeed crash. This is what grid *paging* is for, coupled with on-demand ajax. Your grid should only pull the data needed to display the current page of data when the page is changed. You should not load everything ahead of time.

Here's an example on the SlickGrid github site: http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

Here's more information: https://github.com/teleological/slickback/wiki/Pagination

Comment: Hmmm, I thought that paging was built into SlickGrid internally...I think you may have put me on the right track.

Comment: pagination is built into slickgrid, but you need a combination of pagination and on-demand loading. If you loaded ten thousand rows into memory, pagination is possible but that's still ten thousand rows in memory when you're only showing fifty at a time. You want the grid to use ajax only when switching a page. You shouldn't be loading them all ahead of time :)

Comment: So, the endgame here is to have a grid that will allow users to filter the data into smaller amounts that they will actually observe and use.  It seems like what you're saying is that the mere size of the slickdata object is causing the page to crash (please correct me if I'm misunderstanding you).  So, again correct me if I'm wrong, you're saying to set up my JSON/web server interaction to only retrieve data from the server when the user filters or scrolls?

Comment: I think I am going to restructure the whole thing entirely to function in a way that the browser can actually handle.  This answer is the basis for my overhaul.  Thanks @x0n!

Comment: @peppajack yes - it's the sheer size of data you've loaded into memory that's causing the browser to crash. Granted, browsers shouldn't crash but running out of memory is a good way to do it.